# Dependable dropdown menus with jQuery, PHP and SQL

Tags: php, jquery, sql

this weekend i've been trying to use this script To create dependable menus.

It consists of an sql table with three rows: "ID, Master, Name" It later grabs the entries that contain 0 as the "master" and will use the resulting data to populate the first option list

To populate the next selection lists from the database, it uses a combination of the following JS and php:

and the rest of the select lists will populate accordinly.

The problem that i'm having is that After it populates the select lists I would like to have the visitors of the website hit a seach button to perform a search based on the data collected. The problem is that when I submit the form it sends the info stored in the "master" row of the database instead of the info on "name"

I'm Getting

```
index.php?genre=1&fruit=37&colour=39
```

Instead of

```
index.php?genre=Male&fruit=Strawberry&colour=Red
```

I tried to switch `'.$row['name'].'` to `'.$row['id'].`

But that was a no go, I also tried to only use '.$row['id'].' and it just messed up with the forms. Is there anyway I can accomplish what i'm looking for so that i can send the values selected on the fields to the url?

Thanks in advanced for any help on this one.

Comment: Please shorten your question as much as possible. I'm sure not all of the code you posted is relevant. The shorter you can make it, the more likely you'll get answers.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior that you mentioned is normal as submitting a form automatically sends the value, instead of the text, of the selected option. The switch that you mentioned (`'.$row['name'].' to '.$row['id'].`)should work fine. If it is messing up the forms, please provide more information on what you mean by messing up the forms.

Otherwise, here is a possible solution. It's not the most elegant solution and is probably best suited for simple forms that do not require further complexities but basically, generate the querystring and redirect manually. This is based on the original example that you linked to at http://www.ssdtutorials.com/tutorials/series/dependable-dropdown.html.

JS:

```
var formObject = {
        run: function (obj) {
            obj.nextAll('.update').html('<option value="">----</option>').attr('disabled', true);
            var id = obj.attr('id');
            var v = obj.val();
            jQuery.getJSON('http://jquery-dependable-dropdown.ssdtutorials.com/mod/update.php', {
                id: id,
                value: v
            }, function (data) {
                if (!data.error) {
                    obj.next('.update').html(data.list).removeAttr('disabled');
                } else {
                    obj.nextAll('.update').html('<option value="">----</option>').attr('disabled', true);
                }
            });
        }
    };
    $(function () {

        $('.update').live('change', function () {
            formObject.run($(this));
        });

        $('#submitButton').click(function () {
            window.location.href = 'test.php?gender=' + $('#gender').find(':selected').text() + '&category=' + $('#category').find(':selected').text() + '&colour=' + $('#colour').find(':selected').text();
        });

    });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<form id="theForm" action="" method="post">
    <select name="gender" id="gender" class="update">
        <option value="">Select one</option>
        <option value="1">Male</option>
        <option value="2">Female</option>
    </select>
    <select name="category" id="category" class="update" disabled="disabled">
        <option value="">----</option>
    </select>
    <select name="colour" id="colour" class="update" disabled="disabled">
        <option value="">----</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" id="submitButton" value="submit">
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BUJnf/1/

Hope that helps a bit!